# How to have a link that does not overwrite the URL

Tags: url, backbone.js

I have a link that I typically would have href="#".  I would like the url to stay the same when it is clicked, but it seems like backbone copies and pastes the link to the URL no matter what it is.  I even put 
`<a href="javascript:alert('true')>Link</a>` 
and the browsers URL was "localhost:5000/javascript:alert('true').

How can I get backbone to refrain from copy and pasting the link to the broswers URL

Comment: Then don't include an `href` attribute on your anchors: `<a>Link</a>`

Comment: I'm guessing OP is doing that because browsers don't style un-`href`ed `<a>` tags the same way way they style `<a href...>` tags.  But you're absolutely right: they could just do that, and fix the styling problems with CSS (if they didn't want to use the `return false`/`e.preventDefault` solution as I proposed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those "it's a feature not a bug" type of things.  Backbone does that on purpose, for (at least) two reasons:

1. it gives a URL that users can copy/paste, email to each other, etc. and still take them to the correct place in your site; without such URL manipulation that's impossible
2. it allows for browser-based back/forward functionality (in browsers that don't yet support the history API)

There's probably other reasons too, but that's all I can think of at the moment.  The point is, this is what the Backbone router is supposed to do.  Using it, and then wondering how to make it not manipulate the URL is somewhat akin to using an `<span>` on the page and asking how to get let the user edit its text.

If you don't want that functionality, don't use the Router at all; just have your views invoke each other.

Comment: The issue is that I have an anchor tag being used as a button.  I do use the router to switch between views, and I like that functionality, but I dont want my url to always be # if the person clicks on that one button

Comment: Just return false from that button's event handler; that will make jQuery call `e.preventDefault()`, which will prevent your button/link from changing the URL.

Comment: Also I should note, for completeness, that you can use `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` to avoid hashes in *some* browsers, but only the history API-supporting ones.

Comment: I ended up just switching the <a> to a <div>  it took some extra css/js to do it but it did the trick